# Angularjs ng-model updates the variable for input element not for div element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So I'm new to Angularjs, but I'm trying to write the code for a comment area where users can put their comments. For this I'm using a div element with conteneditable="true" property. Here's my code for html:

```
<html>
    <script src="./includes/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./includes/angular.route.js"></script>
    <script src="./includes/angular.sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="./includes/test.js"></script>  
    <body ng-app="testapp" ng-controller="cnt1"> 

        <div contenteditable="true" ng-model='comment'>{{comment}} </div>
        <input ng-model='comment' type='text'/><br>

        <div>{{comment}}</div>    
    </body>    
</html>
```

and here is the .js code

```
/// <reference path="./angular.min.js"
/// <reference path="./angular.route.js"
/// <reference path="./angular.sanitize.js"
/// <reference path="./jq/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"
/// <reference path="./moment.min.js"
/// <reference path="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.4.7/webfont.js"

var app = angular.module("testapp", ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize']);
app.controller("cnt1", function ($scope, $http, $rootScope, $timeout) {
    $scope.comment = "type here";

});
```

I don't understand why ng-model updates the "comment" variable in the input element but it does not update the variable for the div element! Any help is appreciated! 
And if $apply() can fix this, how should I use it so it updates the "comment" variable in the div element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

> The `ngModel` directive binds an `input`, `select`, `textarea` (or custom form control) to a property on the scope using NgModelController, which is created and exposed by this directive.

`div`s are not listed there. :(

If you're still looking to work w/ a `div`, take a look at the example here! https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#custom-control-example